# JSP + View bean complete example

Tags: java, jsp, view, javabeans

I found this interesting tutorial that explains the concept of view bean with some code snippets http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/i-extreme5/, but I'd like to view a complete (simple) web application in a real world scenario using plain JSP and view beans (not using struts, spring or jsf framework).
Thanks for pointing me to such a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a damn ;) old tutorial, aged from the time that JSTL and EL *just* became alive and that the use of *scriptlets* became discouraged. Nowadays this stuff has been evolved to component based MVC frameworks like JSF (learn the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp/2097732#2097732)).

I am not aware of real life samples, but you can find another one in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-use-in-jspservlet.html) which should be complete.